# font style not working in firefox

Tags: css

the following font style code does not work in firefox, I tested it in chrome and iexplorer and it works, so must be a compatibility problem.

```
font: italic normal normal normal 12px/15.3599996566772px Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
```

Can someone confirm it, or maybe there's an alternative for firefox.

FIX:

```
font: italic normal normal 12px/15.3599996566772px Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Is the `Allow pages to choose their own fonts` option selected?

Comment: Yes, that option is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FireFox, you should set all the properties without using the shorthand property.  `font:` is the shorthand property for many other font properties:

Instead it should look like this:

```
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
color: blue;
```

### http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

### http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Comment: Thanks, that link helped me.

Comment: Did it answer your question?  Do you need additional help?

Comment: There is no general reason to avoid `font` shorthand in general. Firefox can handle it. This issue is an isolated bug and can be avoided in many ways. And w3schools should not be used as any kind of reference, or at all, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, Why is W3Schools a bad reference?  I learned all of my CSS and JS from that site.  Well, most of it.

Comment: font-size 20px? Sorry I got lost.

Comment: Whatever you want can be put there.  That was just an example . . .

Comment: Hmmm right, I thought you were going to use my values.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Firefox. In the Developer Tools, no errors are shown, but when inspecting style sheets, the styles for the element are empty.

A quick workaround is to remove of the `normal` keywords (or all of them, since they are redundant: all sub-properties not set explicitly in a `font` shorthand are set to their initial values).

P.S. Your code is correct, Firefox just does not handle it well. As a reference to `font` shorthand syntax (if you use it), use the [W3C CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-shorthand).

Comment: Yes, I just did that: [as here says](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp) following the order of the property values: font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height